# Can I evenly divide current between different parts of a circuit without one pulling more than its designated amount?

Tags: voltage, amperage

Here is a picture of what I am trying to ask:

```
_________   //====1 ==== LED
|Battery|   ======2 ==== Very high power LED
|_______|   ======3 ==== low power LED
            \\====4 =)   Nothing
```

Is there a way to divide the power from a battery into 4 different + and -? The key part is that each one will have 1/4 of the total voltage/current.

The way I understand it is that each line will pull everything it needs. Is there a way of limiting it so that channel 2 will not be fully on, but channel 4 will have equivalent voltage and current?

Comment: You limit the current by varying the voltage, thus breaking your requirements. Remember Ohms law: V = I * R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to connect those loads in parallel.  Get rid of the "nothing".  You don't have to specify nothing (unless you mean short circuit, in which case you don't want to do that - still get rid of it)

Comment: will this give each one an exactly equal voltage and amperage? If the very high power led requires more amperage than it has in it's 1/4 portion (thus dimmer), but the low power one has a surplus?

Comment: Yes, you want a parallel connection.  The voltage will be equal for all, and they will pull different currents.  Don't take this the wrong way, but you need to research basic analog circuits before posting on an electrical engineering forum.  I can tell from you line of question that you don't have a good understanding of voltage or current and it would take too long to adequately describe it here.  You should do your due diligence before posting questions like this.  But trust me, you're looking for a parallel connection.

Comment: and do you reccomend a book or website (aside from school) that I can learn all of this content?

Comment: If you have a basic background in physics I would jump right into electrical circuits (https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circuits).  Really you can just google "electrical circuits beginners lessons".  I'm sure there's plenty of good sites out there.